# Как правильно подключить статическую библиотеку в Makefile?

Tags: makefile, openwrt

При сборке пакета под OpenWRT папку с исходниками библиотеки поместил в исходник программы,

```
../uqmi/libubox
```

там же собрал статическую библиотеку libubox.a
    ../uqmi/libubox/libubox.a

Пробую подключить - прописываю в Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS = -L./libubox -lubox
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
/home/ruslan/OpenWRT_Lanedo_MM/lanedo-openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_r2_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.6.4/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./libubox/libubox.a when searching for -lubox
```

Как правильно в Makefile uqmi указать как подключить ее при сборке?

Операционная система - **Fedora 18**

**UDP**
MAKE запускаю кросскомпиляцией в окружении OpenWRT

```
make package/uqmi/{clean,compile} V=s
```

В топовом Makefile пакета прописал предварительную сборку libubox

```
define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/libubox 
    $(call Build/Prepare/Default)
endef
```

Comment: Пожалуйста подробнее. Поскольку ругается на несовместимость libubox, то приведённых данных недостаточно.

Comment: Из стандартного libubox потребовалось сделать статическую либу и его исходники сделать частью исходников uqmi - a)для экономии места b)чтобы получить возможность включить часть необходимых хедеров из из libubox, поскольку стандартным способом gcc от linaro имеющийся в OpenWRT категорически не хотел подключать  <libubox/util.h> GNU Makefile не было ни для libubox ни для uqmi - используется CMake. На его основе были сделаны Makefile. В libubox.a добавлены дополнительно файлы blobmsg.* (В OpenWRT из них собирается отдельная либа - libblobmsg_json.so.

Comment: Для подключения в Makefile uqmi используется LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections -Llibubox -Wl,-Bstatic -lubox -Wl,-Bdynamic
При компиляции под mipsel-uclibc-4.6.3 (прошивка asus oleg's based) все собирается,в Makefile.top - 
uqmi: uqmi/libubox/libubox.a uqmi/uqmi
 $(MAKE) -C $@ all
uqmi/libubox/libubox.a: uqmi/libubox
 $(MAKE) -C $< all
uqmi-install:
 install -d $(INSTALLDIR)/uqmi
 $(MAKE) -C uqmi INSTALL=install INSTALLDIR="$(INSTALLDIR)/uqmi" install
 $(STRIP) $(INSTALLDIR)/uqmi/usr/sbin/uqmi
Пытаюсь понять, как изменить Makefile OpenWRt или самого uqmi

Comment: @Руслан, ОС (в которой make запускаете) какая?

Вообще, если линкер ругается, то скорее всего при сборке .a что-то не так с указанием архитектуры, для которой собираете.

Вот это место и посмотрите.

Comment: Всё равно непонятно. Несовместимость библиотеки может иметь место, например, при несовпадении архитектур. И Вы бы хоть текст отформатировали (в комментариях это -- пустая строка перед и после и четыре пробела перед началом строки)

Comment: make я запускаю используя Makefile и копилятoр OpenWRT (gcc-linaro) дальше запускается Makefile в самих исходниках. Все стандартно 

    make package/uqmi/{clean,compile} V=s

Comment: Вот вывод команды file 

    [ruslan@localhost FMK_Keenetic_V2]$ file '/home/rusink/OpenWRT_Lanedo_MM   /lanedo-openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/uqmi-r-0.0.1/libubox/libubox.a' 
    /home/ruslan/OpenWRT_Lanedo_MM/lanedo-openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_r2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/uqmi-r-0.0.1/libubox/libubox.a: current ar archive
[rusink@localhost FMK_Keenetic_V2]$

Comment: @Руслан, еше раз, **ОС какая???**

Comment: @avp судя по openwrt - linux, ядро в районе 2.4 и прочее, собирает под одну из архитектур роутера, вряд-ле это x86, я думаю в этом и проблема, либу собрал под x86 и пытается залинковать ее статически с кодом под (блин вылетело какие там процы обычно в таких железках)

Comment: Я имеюю в виду make запускается непосредственно на роутере, или делается кросс?

Если бы все происходит в линуксе, то откуда проблема с GNU Makefile?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Надо было в топовый Makefile пакета (OpenWRT) в секции Build/Prepare добавить флаги при сборке статической библиотеки:

```
define Build/Prepare
mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
$(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
$(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/libubox \
 $(MAKE_ARGS) \
    CC="$(TARGET_CC)" CFLAGS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS)" \
    LDFLAGS="$(TARGET_LDFLAGS)"
$(call Build/Prepare/Default)
```

endef

Без этого libubox собирался под x86, а не кросскомпиляцией под MIPS

В Makefile собираемой программы (uqmi) поставил соответственно:

```
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections -Llibubox -Wl,-Bstatic -lubox -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Спасибо всем, кто помогал.